# A jar has four chips colored red, green, blue, and yellow...

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

A jar has four chips colored red, green, blue, and yellow.
A person draws a chip, observes its color, and returns it. Chips are now drawn
repeatedly, without replacement, until the first chip drawn is selected again.
What is the mean number of draws required?

I am supposed to be using tail probabilities to solve this as shown below

X= # of draws required to draw red again (arbitrarily picked red)

E[X]=P(X≥1)+P(X≥2)+P(X≥3)+P(X≥4) which gives
E[X]=    1 + 3/4  + 3/4(2/3)+ 3/4(2/3)(1/2) = 5/2

I am having trouble coming up with the probabilities my professor got above. Can someone help me understand this?

Thank you

Comment: Where are you having problems?  It's clear, say, that $P(X≥1)=1$, yes?  Let's work out $P(X≥2)$.  For that one, the only way it can take $<2$ is if the first two are duplicates...the probability of that is $\frac 14$, thus $P(X≥2)=1-\frac 14=\frac 34$.  Now try the next two.

Comment: A suggestion:  perhaps it is easier to work out $P(X=1),P(X=2),P(X=3),P(X=4)$.  Then you can read off your professor's values.